# Number of trails in a complete digraph with loops

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Consider a directed graph $G_n = (V, E)$ where $V = \{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ and $E=\{e_{ij}\ \forall\ i,j\in [\![1,n]\!]\}$, ie. all possible edges exist, including from a vertice to itself.

I'm trying to find an approximation (at least, the exact number would be better) on the number $f(G_n)$ of trails (walks with no repeated edges) existing in such a graph.

It's clear that the number of such paths must be divisible by $n$ by symmetry, but aside from that I have no idea how to go about it without enumerating them. If my computations are correct, $f(G_1)=1, f(G_2)=24, f(G_3)=1884$.

I have also managed to find formulas for the number of paths of length $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$ in $G_n$ for any $n$ but I don't see any obvious generalization. Assuming $f_k(G_n)$ is the number of paths of length $k$ in $G_n$, we have:

$$f(G_n) = \sum_{k\in [\![0,n^2]\!]} f_k(G_n)$$

My calculations (if thery are right) also give the following results:

$$f_0(G_n) = n$$
$$f_1(G_n) = n^2$$
$$f_2(G_n) = n(n-1)(n+1)$$
$$f_3(G_n) = n(n-1)^2(n+2)$$
$$f_4(G_n) = n^2(n-1)(n^2 + n - 5)$$
(that last one especially may be wrong)

I would like to know if there is any known approximation or formula for either $f_k(G_n)$ or $f(G_n)$. If none of these are known, even an algorithm computing them in polynomial time (ie. without enumerating them all) would greatly help me, maybe using the multiple symmetries in the considered graphs. I have looked around but only found such algorithms for DAGs, which this clearly isn't.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are counting.  $G_2$ has $2$ nodes and $4$ directed edges (including the two loops).  Can you list all $24$ "trails" in your $f(G_2) = 24$?

Comment: @antkam Agreed; for $G_2$ I count one trail of length $0$, four trails of length 1, six trails of length $2$, eight trails of length $3$ and four trails of length $4$ make for a total of $23$ trails.

Comment: @Servaes - same here, so at least _we_ agree.  :)  $24$ would make sense (together with $f_0(G_n) = n$) if "starting at node $v$ and never moving" were distinct for different $v$...

Comment: @antkam I guess this depends on whether a trail is a list of edges or a list of vertices? Given that the length is the number of edges, I interpreted it as a list of edges, but both make for fine definitions.

Comment: I used antkam's definition, meaning you have two trails of length $0$ (starting from $v_1$ and not moving, starting from $v_2$ and not moving). If it's easier with the other definition that's fine with me.

Comment: OK, then I like @Servaes viewpoint of "a list of vertices", in which case your question is equivalent to: how many non-empty sequences of $[1,n]^\infty$ are there s.t. in the sequence, the $2$-long subsequence $xy$ does not appear at two different positions in the sequence, for any $xy \in [1,n]^2$.  Do you agree this is equivalent?

Comment: Incidentally, it is clear that $f_k(G_n) \le n^{k+1}$ because with $k$ edges you only have a list of $k+1$ nodes.  So your formula for $f_4$ is definitely wrong since it contains $n^6$.

Comment: I absolutely agree. In fact, this is the approach I've been using for computing the values above (with letters instead of $[1, n]$), because if up to $k$ different values can be used in such a sequence, then by symmetry you only have to consider $1$ sequence in $k!$. I also edited $f_4$, I had accidentally slipped in one factor too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer - answer only for the max length case (length $=n^2 + 1$ case), plus a loose upperbound based on that.

We take the alternate (and equivalent) view that the OP is counting the number of non-empty sequences $\in [1,n]^\infty$ where no length-$2$ subsequence $xy$ appears more than once (for any $xy \in [1,n]^2$ including possibly $x=y$).  For shorthand we will call such sequences "good" sequences.  Obviously the maximum length a "good" sequence can have is $n^2+1$.

A [de Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of order $p$ on the alphabet $\{1,2,...,q\}$ is a cyclic sequence in which every possible length-$p$ sequence on the alphabet occurs exactly once as a subsequence.  In the OP context, we have $p=2, q=n$.  (Warning: the wikipedia article uses the parameter/variable $n$ differently!  The OP uses $n$ as alphabet size, while the wikipedia article uses $n$ as the order, i.e. the length of the subsequences.)

A de Bruijn sequence (of order $2$) is equivalent to a max-length good sequence, since every length-$2$ subsequence appeared once.  In the OP such a max-length sequence has length $n^2 + 1$, while the de Bruijn sequences are cyclic and have length $n^2$, but this is a difference that makes no difference: a max-length good sequence must have first and final symbols being the same (because it's an Eulerian cycle, i.e. start node = end node) so it can be written as a cyclic sequence.  In short, de Bruijn (cyclic) sequences (of order $2$) are the max-length good (linear) sequences.

According to wiki, the no. of distinct de Bruijn cyclic sequences is

$$ {(q!)^{q^{p-1}} \over q^p} $$

However, this count apparently treats all sequences which are rotations as one (i.e. as non-distinct).  For the OP purpose, each of the $n^2$ different start positions in a cycle are distinct linear sequences.  We therefore have:

$$ f_{n^2}(G_n)=n^2 \times {(n!)^{n^{2-1}} \over n^2} = (n!)^n$$

Sanity check: the no. of length-$n^2$ sequences (not necessarily good) $= n^{n^2} = n^{n \cdot n} = (n^n)^n > (n!)^n$

---

**CORRECTION:** Originally I thought it's "obvious" that $f_k(G_n) \le f_{n^2}(G_n)$, because I thought any $(k+1)$-long good sequence (i.e. $k$-edge path) can be continued (by adding subsequent edges) into a full de Bruijn cycle (at a specific start position).  I.e. I thought such a shorter path is a truncation of some de Bruijn cycle.  If true, this would be a $1$-to-many map and would imply the upperbound $f(G_n) \le n^2 f_{n^2}(G_n) = n^2 (n!)^n.$

However, this is false.  By exhaustive listing, we have $f_3(G_2) = 8, f_4(G_2) = 4$.  What happened is that some of the shorter paths, e.g. $0010$ aka $(00, 01, 10)$, cannot be continued into a complete de Bruijn cycle (i.e., it is not a truncation of a de Bruijn cycle).  In this case we "missed" the chance to use the loop $11$ and cannot add it back *at the end*.  And of course, adding it back at some other position (and there might be a choice of many positions) would break the $1$-to-many map, and that's why $f_k > f_{n^2}$ can happen.

Comment: +1 Nice start! A minor note; the name is *de Bruijn*, not *de Brujin*.

Comment: oops!  spelling fixed.  thanks

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Plugging in $n=3$ does give me the values I computed myself, so that seems right. Interestingly enough $f_7(G_3)$ and $f_8(G_3)$ have the same value which is double that of $f_9(G_3)$, so there might be something to explore there. However, wouldn't that invalidate your upper bound? I imagine you assumed that $f_i(G_n) \le f_{n^2}(G_n)$ which fails for $n=3, i=8$. Other than that your upper bound formula gives $1944$ which is pretty close to the value of $1884$ I found. I will wait a few days for possible other answers, otherwise I will accept yours.

Comment: Yes I had implicitly assumed that $f_i(G_n) \le f_{n^2}(G_n)$...  Apologies if I'm wrong (and I will edit).  How did you compute $f_{7,8,9}(3)$?  Exhaustive search?  I am esp. surprised that you said $f_{n^2 - 1}(G_n) \neq f_{n^2}(G_n)$ as I thought the two sets of "trails" are bijective.

Comment: I am indeed wrong about $f_k \le f_{n^2}$ and have updated my answer to explain (partly) what happened.  Sorry!  Still curious about how you calculate $f_{7,8,9}(G_3)$ and if it is by exhaustive search.

Comment: I did an algorithm search using symmetry, generating all possible configurations (and not trails). There are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ trails in each configuration going through $k$ vertices, so I all I had to do was generate the list of such configurations (for ex. $(e_i, e_i, e_j, e_k, e_j)$ is one of length 4 with 3 vertices). There were respectively $4, 12, 21, 39, 58, 72, 72$ and $36$ configurations for $f_{2,...,9}(G_3)$ that I found with a little script. I am sure there is more that could be done to limit the search space even further, maybe using induction, but I fear it's beyond my level.